# Why Bhishma had to suffer the most in MahaBharat war?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhishma

Bhishma was a great Dharmatma without any doubt/question. He always follows his dharma. But in war of Mahabharat he was the one who suffer more than anyone else. Even korwas (who was key reason of war) didn't suffer that much as compared to Bhishma. So why a great Dharmatma like Bhishma had to suffer more than anyone else in war? There was many sinful warrior were there but still suffering of Bhishma was greatest!!

Earlier I thought it was because of Bhishma's one action which he has done in deeyut sabhaa. He decided to remain silence on Draupadi's vastra harana, hence because of this act of him, He had to suffer so badly in Mahabharat war. But few days ago I read story which was totally different and unheard. Here it is...

> भीष्म पितामह रणभूमि में शरशैया पर पड़े थे। हल्का सा भी हिलते तो शरीर में घुसे बाण भारी वेदना के साथ रक्त की पिचकारी सी छोड़ देते। ऐसी दशा में उनसे मिलने सभी आ जा रहे थे। श्री कृष्ण भी दर्शनार्थ आये। उनको देखकर भीष्म जोर से हँसे और कहा.... आइये जगन्नाथ।.. आप तो सर्व ज्ञाता हैं। सब जानते हैं, बताइए मैंने ऐसा क्या पाप किया था जिसका दंड इतना भयावह मिला?
>
> **कृष्ण:** पितामह! आपके पास वह शक्ति है, जिससे आप अपने पूर्व जन्म देख सकते हैं। आप स्वयं ही देख लेते।
>
> **भीष्म:** देवकी नंदन! मैं यहाँ अकेला पड़ा और कर ही क्या रहा हूँ? मैंने सब देख लिया ...अभी तक 100 जन्म देख चुका हूँ। मैंने उन 100 जन्मो में एक भी कर्म ऐसा नहीं किया जिसका परिणाम ये हो कि मेरा पूरा शरीर बिंधा पड़ा है, हर आने वाला क्षण ...और पीड़ा लेकर आता है।
>
> **कृष्ण:** पितामह ! आप एक भव और पीछे जाएँ, आपको उत्तर मिल जायेगा।
>
> भीष्म ने ध्यान लगाया और देखा कि 101 भव पूर्व वो एक नगर के राजा थे। ...एक मार्ग से अपनी सैनिकों की एक टुकड़ी के साथ कहीं जा रहे थे। एक सैनिक दौड़ता हुआ आया और बोला "राजन! मार्ग में एक सर्प पड़ा है। यदि हमारी टुकड़ी उसके ऊपर से गुजरी तो वह मर जायेगा।"
>
> भीष्म ने कहा " एक काम करो। उसे किसी लकड़ी में लपेट कर झाड़ियों में फेंक दो।" सैनिक ने वैसा ही किया।...उस सांप को एक लकड़ी में लपेटकर झाड़ियों में फेंक दिया। दुर्भाग्य से झाडी कंटीली थी। सांप उनमें फंस गया। जितना प्रयास उनसे निकलने का करता और अधिक फंस जाता।... कांटे उसकी देह में गड गए। खून रिसने लगा। धीरे धीरे वह मृत्यु के मुंह में जाने लगा।... 5-6 दिन की तड़प के बाद उसके प्राण निकल पाए।
>   ....
>
> **भीष्म:** हे त्रिलोकी नाथ। आप जानते हैं कि मैंने जानबूझ कर ऐसा नहीं किया। अपितु मेरा उद्देश्य उस सर्प की रक्षा था। तब ये परिणाम क्यों?
>
> **कृष्ण:** तात श्री! हम जान बूझ कर क्रिया करें या अनजाने में ...किन्तु क्रिया तो हुई न। उसके प्राण तो गए ना।... ये विधि का विधान है कि जो क्रिया हम करते हैं उसका फल भोगना ही पड़ता है।.... आपका पुण्य इतना प्रबल था कि 101 भव उस पाप फल को उदित होने में लग गए। किन्तु अंततः वह हुआ।....

I don't know how much this story is correct(since it's from some random source) and how much my earlier view was correct on it. What was actual reason of Bhishma's this level of suffering?

Comment: [The Karmic reason why Bhishma had to spend the final days of his life on a Bed of Arrows](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15246/the-karmic-reason-why-bhishma-had-to-spend-the-final-days-of-his-life-on-a-bed-o).

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Great Find :) I got very scared after reading my mentioned story. Because 2 days ago I was using my laptop in night before sleep (as usual). Some little insects were also flying in room. I finished my work and shutdown laptop and close lid of it But one of the insect got stucked in laptop when I close lid of it. I didn't notice that time. On next day at night when I put up lid of laptop then found one flying insec was in there and stucked between keyboard and lid for around 24 hours. [ Contine...]

Comment: @Triyuginarayanmani I feel bad and after then all feel scared coz I have read my mentioned story. So I started to think that I will also have to keep stuck for whole day in a narrow place where we can't even move our arms and legs. Even that thought is scare and I am still scared of this thought. That's why I asked this question here to know whether I will be have same suffereing which that insect had coz of me. Your given link says different story, So I shud consider this story imaginary? Will I stop thinking of being trapped like that insect since nothing like that can happened?

Comment: This ma help you https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/is-it-wise-to-kill-an-insect-just-because-it-is-bothering-you

Comment: You may want to undelete your [this Qn](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21216/1049). See the related discussion on that topic, [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40288916#40288916). A deletion of a Qn may result in adverse effect on your profile as noted by Sinister.

Comment: @iammilind Undeleted, and read all your discussion in given link. Got your point.